# How can I convert my Access database (.accdb) to SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, ms-access

How can I convert my Access database (.accdb) to an SQLite database(.sqlite)?

Comment: First of all you want .db or .sqlite ? cas u have tagged android

Comment: I tried to use SQLite browser, and I can manage to create a sqlite database and import the access data, but when it saves, it saves as a file with no extension, I tried to manually add .sqlite, but it doesn't work...

Comment: I want sqlite, I want a SQlite Manager on my android device to be able to read it

Comment: So nothing to do with Access, is it?

Comment: Can you run the file command on the saved file, read it, post it somewhere, or otherwise show what it actually created?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use several step algoritm:
1. Export (convert) Access table or query to Excel file
2. Save Excel file as CSV file.
3. Use any SQLLite manager (for example, phpLiteAdmin) to import data from CSV file to exist SQLLite table.

Except Android and IOS, that use SQLLite, there are still webhostings, that use no more database engine, except for SQLLite.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to convert a structure of db you shoud use any DB-modeling tools:

- create new model from existing Access Database
- generate sql scripte for creating SQLite database
- use this script in SQL helper

2) If you want to import data from Access Database to your android app. I think you can do case #1, migrate all data from Access Database to temporary SQLite database, save it to asset folder and rewrite from asset to internal SQLite database during first app. start